# How change the order of subviews in a UIScrollView by dragging?

Tags: image, animation, uiscrollview, drag

This question without answer after googled and stackoverflowed.

I have a horizontal scrollview, and I'll added some photos (setImage in UIButton) as subviews into it, what I need to do is dragging one UIButton and move to a new position then drop, that's it, works like timeline of iMovie, people can drag one frame to a new position, purpose of this operation to change order of frames.

What should I do with it? or should use something like UITabelView (with just one row) that can rearrange photo thumbnail by dragging with built-in feature?
  Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! I would described what I tried and what I didn't. For example, did you try using jquery dragabble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a answer from Xcode sample named Autoscroll, under sample grounp of ScrollViewSuite, they does what exactly I want to do. I dont know why so few people talking about the trick.